# SSRS Not Displaying Pictures from SharePoint On-Premises

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, reporting-services, ntlm

Lately I have been working on a solution that would allow `.rdlc` files from an `ASP.NET Webforms` page to display images that are stored in a `SharePoint On-Premises` server that runs separately from the company's intranet website. Before SharePoint was added to the domain, older `.rdlc` files' pictures were loaded by impersonating a dummy user (hardcoding their username and password into a static C# variable that utilizes the `advapi32` library) to view files in an SMB network share.

I initially looked into using the SharePoint REST API to retrieve the data. [Following the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom), I intended to utilize an `HttpWebRequest` with an OAuth or Bearer token, but then I wondered if it would be possible to use `NTLM` to authenticate users with a `WebClient`. Wrongly assuming `NTLM` would work by tapping into the credentials of the user logged into the client computer, the solution I came up with was as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
...
protected void ProcessedImageBytes(string uri, DataTable picturesTable)
{
    byte[] imageBytes;

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // The uri variable is just the link to the SharePoint file.
        imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
    }

    DataRow newRow = picturesTable.NewRow();
    newRow["PictureBytes"] = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    picturesTable.Rows.Add(newRow);
}
```

From here, the program takes the `DataRow` text and supplies it to a `ReportDataSource` for the report itself.

What I did not understand was that `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` actually looks into **the host computer's identity** and authorizes the `WebClient` from there. This meant that during my testing, running this report from my PC, the report loaded as intended because the identity was set to my profile and I had access to the SharePoint folder, but the identity used by the host server of the website was **NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**, as I discovered by writing `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` into the code for the live page.

As of now, I am unsure which direction to go. I would like to allow our system to display images from SharePoint links using NTLM, but it seems the only way to do this is to once again write the username and password of the required user directly into the C# code. Many of the solutions I read about are catered to SharePoint Online using Azure AD and/or Microsoft Graph, which I do not have at my disposal.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: You could always use a configuration file of some sort. If your deployment server is far enough, encrypt the credentials and store the decryption password as an environmental variable on your server.

Comment: @PrinceOwen I am thinking of trying something like that, but instead of user credentials, we put a token into the Web.Config file. Only thing is I need to find out how to get an authorization token that lasts practically forever.

Comment: If you can't find that, you could automate a renewal and store it in the config. Maybe weekly, when users log in or something.

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?